# UTF-8 WordPress Encoding Issue

Tags: wordpress, encoding, utf-8, text-editor, visual-editor

We have a WordPress website which is suddenly displaying text and links that look like this:

[Note the odd characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xucaq.jpg)

These links are generated using the EasyAzon plugin, however I do not think this problem is related to EasyAzon.  If I turn off that plugin, that same text on the site displays as follows:

[Note the odd chars display even with the plugin off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd2BS.jpg)

That same piece of text displays in the Wordpress visual and text editors as follows.  You can see that neither editor displays the odd characters:

[Note the odd characters are not in the visual editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqSvo.jpg)

[Note the odd characters are not in the text editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH79H.jpg)

If I comment out the db_charset and db_collate lines in wp-config.php, this problem goes away:

//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');

Or, if I keep both lines and change utf8 to latin1, the problem again goes away.

define('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

But as a side effect of both of these changes/fixes to the wp-config.php file, it breaks the editor.  When editing any post, the editor window is blank (both in the visual and text editors).  It's not until I return those lines above to this state that the editor returns to normal:

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

How can I resolve the issue with the odd characters displaying on the website without the side effect of breaking the WP editor?